# Filtrar objetos com critério no array dentro dele

Tags: javascript

Por que não estou conseguindo retornar apenas os objetos que contenham a disciplina `Matemática`?

Estou utilizando os métodos `map()` , `filter()` e, dentro do `filter()`, o `includes()`, mas está retornando todos os objetos.

Será que não dá para utilizar encadeado como fiz, tendo que ser desencadeado os métodos:

```js
let dados = [
  {nome: 'Noah', disciplinas: ['Matemática', 'Geografia', 'Inglês']},
  {nome: 'Gael', disciplinas: ['Química', 'Geografia', 'Português']},
  {nome: 'Caleb', disciplinas: ['Matemática', 'Física', 'Artes']}
]

let discip = dados.filter(a => a.disciplinas.filter(b => b.includes('Matemática')))

console.log(discip)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando quer filtrar algo basta fazer isso uma vez. Só faria sentido se quisesse ter um filtro dentro do filtro, mas não é o caso, você quer filtrar apenas as pessoas. A disciplina é um critério usado não é outro filtro (pelo que entendi). Então basta pegar a lista de disciplinas e ver se a que está buscando está entre as que a pessoa tem no seu cadastrado, de forma direta e simples.

```js
let dados = [
  {nome: 'Noah', disciplinas: ['Matemática', 'Geografia', 'Inglês']},
  {nome: 'Gael', disciplinas: ['Química', 'Geografia', 'Português']},
  {nome: 'Caleb', disciplinas: ['Matemática', 'Física', 'Artes']}
]

let discip = dados.filter(a => a.disciplinas.includes('Matemática'))

console.log(discip)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/FilterArray.js).

Comment: Certo então, entendi Maniero, realmente abusei do método. Obrigado!